# If $p\circ \phi = p$ then $\phi$ is a deck transformation?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm trying to solve the following question:

> True or False:
>
> Let $p:\tilde{X}\to X$ be a covering map with $\tilde{X}$ path connected and $\phi: \tilde{X}\to\tilde{X}$ a continuous transformation such that $p\circ\phi=p$. Then $\phi$ is a deck transformation.

To prove this is true, I just have to prove that $\phi$ is a homeomorphism. To prove this is false, I have to find a counterexample.

I am almost sure this is false, but I cannot find a counterexample. Some help?

Comment: Can you let $\bar X$ be two copies of $X$ with the obvious map $p$ and let $\phi$ just identify the two components?

Comment: @D.Brogan $\tilde{X}$ must be path connected. I will put it in the question.

Comment: I wrote a silly answer and deleted. There is a counter-example here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80105/why-do-the-definition-of-deck-transformations-requires-homeomorphism?